Finding strings from a list between 2 string conditions that are part of the list
In Google Sheets, I have a list of unique strings that I want to filter based on two conditions. These conditions are two strings within that list. Ultimately, I want to find all the strings, inclusive of my conditions, that are in between.
This is the list in the Google Sheet:



List




Apple


Banana


Pear


Grapes


Kiwi


Mandarin


Papaya


Orange


Tomato


Plum


Watermelon



Based on these two following conditions, I'm trying to get strings that fall in between these two, including these two conditions.



String 1
String 2




Pear
Orange



Ideally, the results will be displayed as an array, that way, the single formula can dynamically change the results based on the 2 conditions.



Expected Results




Pear


Grapes


Kiwi


Mandarin


Papaya


Orange



In terms of error handling, I need to account for 3 type of scenarios:
1. Scenario 1: Error handling when selected conditions not in list order
Conditions:



String 1
String 2




Plum
Kiwi






Expected Results




Nothing



--> Nothing between string selection as String 2 is BEFORE String 1 condition in the list order.
2. Scenario 2: Error handling when String conditions match
Conditions:



String 1
String 2




Mandarin
Mandarin






Expected Results




Mandarin



--> the list of strings are unique, so it will show only one result as it's inclusive of string conditions.
3. Scenario 3: Error handling when String condition #2 is empty, therefore choosing all results post-String 1 that are not empty.
Conditions:



String 1
String 2




Mandarin







Expected Results




Mandarin


Papaya


Orange


Tomato


Plum


Watermelon



Attempts:
I've tried the following 2 formulas but unfortunately I get an error as strings are not considered as numbers in the QUERY function, and the OFFSET attempt doesn't allow me to enter in between.
1.=QUERY(A4:A14,"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 >= '"&C4&"' AND Col 1 <= '"&D4&"'")
2.=OFFSET(A4:A14, MATCH(C4, A4:A14, 0), 0)
Testing Google Sheet link with public edit access: here
Image of current worksheet: 

Try the following in F4:
=let(
list,tocol(A4:A,1),
string1,match(C4,list,0),
string2,ifna(match(D4,list,0),counta(list)),
iferror(chooserows(list,sequence(string2-string1+1,1,string1))))

We are using match the find the positions of the two search strings in the list, then (with appropriate error handling to deal with your described scenarios), using these positions with sequence inside chooserows to show the appropriate rows.

Thank you so much! Worked perfectly

Uses inbetween() to tally the rows which fall between Pear & Orange and then filtering them as output
=let(x,A4:A14,y,row(x)-1,ifna(filter(x,isbetween(row(x),xmatch(C4,x)+y,ifna(xmatch(D4,x)+y,rows(x)+y)))))


Thank you so much! Worked perfectly

Here's how to do that using a lambda to get row numbers:
=let( 
  data, A4:A14, 
  row_, lambda(d, single(filter(row(data), data = d))), 
  start, row_(C4), 
  end, if(len(D4), row_(D4), 9^9), 
  ifna(filter(data, isbetween(row(data), start, end))) 
)

See lambda().
